# Self-locating Strings in $\pi$?

Tags: number-representation, digit-sequences

According to [The Pi-Search Page](http://www.angio.net/pi/), in the first 100 million digits of $\pi$ the following numbers are self-locating: 1, 16470, 44899, 79873884.

The following inefficient code (which also does not handle the case of leading 0 digit) finds 16470 and 44899:

```
Module[{n, k = 5}, n = 10^k - 1; 
  Position[Apply[Equal, Transpose[{Range[n], FromDigits /@ 
    Partition[Rest@First@RealDigits[Pi, 10, n + k], k, 1]}], 1],True]]
```

What is an efficient way to find other "fixed points"—and is there an elegant way to use `FixedPoint` to find self-locating digit sequences?

Comment: `Module[{n, m, k = 5}, n = 10^k - 1; m = 10^(k - 1);
 Pick[Range[m, n], 
  Total /@ Unitize[
    Subtract[
     IntegerDigits /@ 
      Range[m, 
       n], (Partition[First@RealDigits[Pi - 3, 10, n + k - 1], k, 
        1])[[m ;; n]]]], 0]]` is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

This should be able to treat leading zeroes and is ten times faster:

A precompiled function:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {z, _Integer}},
   Block[{b, i, j},
    b = IntegerDigits[z, 10];
    i = z;
    While[Compile`GetElement[a, i] == 0, i++];
    j = 1;
    While[
     j < Length[b] && 
      Compile`GetElement[a, i] == Compile`GetElement[b, j],
     i++;
     j++;
     ];
    Boole[
     j == Length[b] && 
      Compile`GetElement[a, i] == Compile`GetElement[b, j]]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

Running the program (with timing and result):

```
k = 5;
n = 10^k - 1;
a = RealDigits[Pi, 10, n + k - 1, -1][[1]];
pos = Flatten[Position[cf[a, Range[n]], 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
pos
```

> 0.008294
>
> {1, 16470, 43611, 44899}